# Brownian motion: How to compare real versus simulated data

Tags: simulation, brownian-motion

We have one-dimensional experimental data which **we believe** is a result of a brownian motion process.  I would like to generate simulated data using brownian motion in order to evaluate methods for estimating diffusion constant.

Question: I want to know if or to what extent the simulated data approximates the real data.  Do you have any suggestions on how to compare the real versus the simulated data?

I was thinking of taking all my simulated data and obtaining the distribution of mean and standard deviation of its displacements, and somehow comparing that to the analogous distribution of the real data.  Any ideas on this or other alternatives?

Comment: Why not use your data for the simulation? Because the increments of Brownian motion are supposed to be iid, you have available (depending on the form of your data) a potentially large, rich source of increments you can sample from for a simulation.

Comment: Thank you @whuber!  If I understand you correctly, using the increments from the real data would allow simulation of data that looks like real data.  The one thing that I am not sure this would help with is that I am trying to see if I can approximate my real data with a brownian motion model in order to justify inferring a diffusion constant from it, and other parameters, and in general to help in perhaps understanding what is going on.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the distribution of real and simulated data (e.g. increments) by applying one of statistical tests, e.g. [two-sample Kolmigorov-Smirnov test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

Comment: Brownian motion is far more than a univariate distribution.  How, then, do you propose to apply a univariate test like the KS to this problem?

Comment: @whuber I was thinking about comparison of the increments distributions: real vs simulated.

Comment: if you're gonna compare increments, then you need to decide on the increment distance of which,as whuber points out, there are infinitely many. But you must be using a discrete approximation for the brownian motion, right ? So, whatever increment you're using there could be used in the test.

Comment: The clarification about the increments is useful.  However, testing Brownian motion involves more than assessing the distribution of the increments: perhaps more importantly, one needs to test their independence and their stationarity.